# RSA_verify() causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, openssl, segmentation-fault

Teh function below causes a segmentation fault when it gets to the `RSA_verify()` part. I'm a c-beginner so it's hard for me to find the reason for the problem. Maybe someone can point out what I'm doing wrong. It would be very helpful, thanks in advance.

Here's the Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/dsa.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

#define BUF 20000
#define DSS 20

int matchCipherToSign(unsigned char *signPath, char *cipherPath) {
unsigned char *bufCipher = malloc(BUF);
unsigned char *sha = malloc(SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
unsigned char *bufSign = malloc(BUF);
unsigned int retSign;
int ret=0;
int retCipher;
FILE *key;
RSA *rsa = RSA_new();
EVP_MD_CTX ctx;

key = fopen("key.bin", "rb");
if (key == NULL){
    printf("Couldn't open file key.bin.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

retSign = readFile(signPath, bufSign);
if (retSign == 0){
    printf("Couldn't read file %s.\n", signPath);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

retCipher = readFile(cipherPath, bufCipher);
if (retCipher == 0){
    printf("Couldn't open file %s.\n", cipherPath);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

rsa = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(key, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
fclose(key);

if (1!=EVP_DigestInit(&ctx, EVP_sha1())) {
    printf("EVP_DigestInit Error.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (1!=EVP_DigestUpdate(&ctx, bufCipher, retCipher)) {
    printf("VP_DigestUpdate Error.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (1!=EVP_DigestFinal(&ctx, sha, NULL)) {
    printf("EVP_DigestFinal Error.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

ret = RSA_verify(NID_sha1, sha, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH, bufSign, sizeof(bufSign), rsa);

RSA_free(rsa);
free(bufCipher);
free(bufSign);
free(sha);

return ret;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry guys, I've just found my mistake. There was an error in my key-file. :D

Comment: Glad you found the mistake. You should make sure the program doesn't crash at all though, even with malformated data.

Comment: Another error? sizeof(bufSign) will evaluate to the size of the pointer. You probably want the size of the buffer.

Comment: You should run your program under Valgrind to help detect memory errors. When you build your program use `-O0` or `-O1`. Also see [The Valgrind Quick Start Guide](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html).

Comment: @BjornA. You're right! Thanks.
Thanks for the other tips as well. I'll keep that in mind.